# SettingWithCopyWarning error in Python when inserting a new column in the dataframe that normalizes weights to add up to 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Instrument  Issuer Name Sector Name Portfolio Weight    Environment Pillar Score Grade  
0   9433.T  KDDI CORP   Sector A    0.20                Z
1   HES     HESS CORP   Sector B    0.10                Z
2   AXP     AMEX        Sector C    0.10                Z
3   JPM     JPMORGAN    Sector C    0.10                Z
4   CSCO    CISCO       Sector D    0.10                Z
```

I need to normalize the weights and insert a column labeled New Portfolio Weight so that the sum of the portfolio weights = 1.

I used the following code:

```
df['New Portfolio Weight'] = df['Portfolio Weight'].transform(lambda x: x / x.sum())
```

but I got the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

I can't figure out how to fix the error with .loc despite reading all the documentation.
Would anyone know how to fix the error? Thank you so much!

Comment: It is trying to warn you that you are modifying the copy of a dataframe and not the original one. As a best practice, and in order to silence this warning, you could explicitly say, ```df['New Portfolio Weight'] = df['Portfolio Weight'].copy()``` and then use `transform` as - ```df['New Portfolio Weight'] = df['New Portfolio Weight'].transform(lambda x: x / x.sum())```

Comment: Thank you so much Cavin!